# How to apply Entity Framework code first approach to a project

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, nuget

I use Visual Studio 2013 and need to use Entity Framework code first approach in a project. I used NuGet Manager to install EF v6.1 into my project. But I can't create an empty code first model or even a code first model from database although there are two other choices (DB first and Model first).

How I can add Entity Framework code first feature to my project?

Comment: isn't model first the same as code first?

Comment: As I know model first is an approach that we should create model which could be a graphical model too, but in code first approach we just program our classes for example in C# or VB.

Comment: @TMcKeown: definitely not.

Comment: ok, I've only reversed engineered from DB to CodeFirst...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a beginners tutorial for using entity framework code first:
[An Absolute Beginner's Tutorial for understanding Entity Framework's Code First Approach in ASP.NET MVC](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/683942/An-Absolute-Beginners-Tutorial-for-understanding-E)