# Add Migration not working in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2017, entity-framework-migrations, ef-code-first-mapping

I am creating a Web API application using EF with a code-first approach in Visual Studio 2017. I tried to use `enable-migration`, initially I was not working so I installed these packages.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools -Version 2.2.3
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

After installing those packages, `enable-migration` worked for me, but when I tried to add a migration using `Add-Migration FirstMigration` command, it throws an error

> No DbContext was found in assembly 'UserRegistration'. Ensure that you're using the correct assembly and that the type is neither abstract nor generic.

Please help me how to resolve this issue in Visual Studio 2017.

[image]

PS : I have also defined the `DBbConnection` in my `web.config` file:

```
<connectionString>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" 
         connectionString="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=WebAPIDB;Integrated Security=True" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"></add>
</connectionString>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
    public DbSet<ModelClassName> NameForModel {get; set;}
```

Please include the code above in your model class that has properties you want to migrate in the database
please refer to this link [How to apply Entity Framework code first approach to a project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23657655/how-to-apply-entity-framework-code-first-approach-to-a-project) to make it easier for you to understand.